# DB2OLEDB Driver and error messages in SQLException from SQL Server 2016

Tags: java, sql-server, db2, mainframe

We are using SQL Server 2016 with a linked server to zDB2 (mainframe) via Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 Version 5.0.

When executing a failing SQL statement remote on a linked server (zDB2) the error description is clear in SQL studio but useless in Java.

Example of statement (missing schema name):

```
EXEC (N'UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN1=''SOMEVALUE'' WHERE COLUMN2=  ''032'' ') AT ZDB2
```

Gives the following result in SQL Studio:

```
OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "ZDB2" returned message "DB2GRP.TABLENAME IS AN UNDEFINED NAME SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLCODE: -204". 
Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 6 
Could not execute statement on remote server 'ZDB2'.
```

But the following result in a Java SQLException:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not execute statement on remote server 'ZDB2'. 
SQL State: S0001 
SQL Error code: 7215
```

Using a debugger and inspecting the SQL Exception object, it seems the SQLException has no other data on the error.

How can I get a more useful explanation out of the SQLException on what went wrong besides "Could not execute statement on remote server" ?

And where is the documentation of what S0001 and 7215 means ? (I already googled)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently errors from a linked server are stored as warnings on the statement rather than part of the SQLException when using Microsofts JDBC Driver.

This is how i did it:

```
try{
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    SQLWarning sqlWarning = currentStatement.getWarnings();
    if (sqlWarning != null) {
        warning = sqlWarning.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the S0001 and 7215 are responses back from the Microsoft JDBC driver. The DB2 error info is "SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLCODE: -204" which is unfortunately not showing up in the Java output. It looks like the Microsoft driver is substituting it's own sqlstate/code instead of passing along DB2's.

The -204 is "*name* is an undefined name" (as is stated in the text before the sqlstate and code).
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/db2z_n.html

Since you mention Java code, note that DB2 provides a JDBC driver for direct connectivity. That should at least eliminate the possibility of the MS driver interfering with the error codes returned by DB2. You typically have to get the driver and license file from your systems guys--AFAIK, they aren't publicly provided by IBM but they are included with DB2 for z/OS. But I'd recommend trying to use the IBM driver unless there's some compelling reason why you have to use the Microsoft driver--I am confused about the mention of both OLE DB Provider and JDBC.

Comment: 1) My question was not about the DB2 error code and state.
2) I agree with you about using DB2 Connect, however the license for DB2 Connect is too expensive with the amount of cores we are using, so we opted for a cheaper option